# Difference between Ciao REST server and Ciao REST connector and when to use each or the other

Tags: library, ciao-library

I'm reading the [Ciao library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Ciao) and can't make out the difference between [Ciao REST server](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/CiaoRestServer) and [Ciao REST connector](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/CiaoRestConnector).

When is the connector suitable and at what point do I need the server?

This is a graphic of what im thinking to do:

[image: my aduino ciao setup]

Comment: The yun tag was the only i coul set. I would like to set library-ciao.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about "Ciao" but generally a rest server answers requests from a client that is connecting via a rest connector.
You client will use POST, GET, PUT, etc. to ask the server to provide a service.  This could be as simple as "GET .\index.htm" or more likely posting information to be stored in a database.

The server will sit waiting for these requests and will have handling routines for each specific request and might supply a response.

Comment: yes, im fully aware of REST as api but my queston is about the confusing thing that Ciao is used on a microprocessor board that has another cpu processor beside it. It hosts a LininoOS that is a full server. Now im connecting to a Raspberry Pi Server as well and i down't understand the different servers meaning.
Thats why im asking so high level about the difference of the two libraries.

Comment: added a graphic to make it more clea what thee types of systems i mean.